How to change the width of a CSS-grid column based on content dimensions?
I want to create a template for a simple grid of three images in two columns.

Column 1: Image A will have object-fit: cover. It can be cropped and resized as needed.
Column 2: Image B and C must collectively fill the whole height of the screen. They can be cropped at the bottom, but not on the sides or at the top.

Image B and C might have different aspect ratios, and I want to create a piece of code that will fit various ratios. They are also smaller than the final output (ex. they might be 300px in width, but will be displayed at 1000px eventually). Column 2 will then change width based on which aspect ratio images B and C have:
diagram of three possible grid, depending on the aspect ratio of image B and C
I have tried multiple combinations of grid and flexbox, with parameters of 1fr, stretch, max-content, etc... but I can't find the solution. Either image B and C don't fill the full height of column 2, or they do but they are cropped on each side (aka the column does not resize), or they do but appear squished.
I'm not sure if I should do nested grids, or a combination of grid and flexbox, ...
I believe that what must happen is:

make sure that image B and C have the same width
increase the size of B and C (and thus column 2 width) until column 2 is completely filled.
let image A flow and be cropped to fill the remaining space left for column 1.

I just can't figure out how to make that happen :/

Code Snippet.
In this snippet, image B is squarish, image C is wide. Using a combination of B+B, B+C or C+C in column 2 would simulate the three options I illustrated in the picture above.


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.template {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1777px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
}

.column-1 {
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.column-1 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.column-2 {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.column-2 img {
    width: 100%;
}
<body>
    <div class="template">
        <div class="column-1">
            <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/8MHbl4HT.png" target="_blank">
        </div>
        <div class="column-2">
            <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JCTnUi2C.png" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/oJW3N1vA.png" target="_blank">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>




Images for the code snippet:

imageA
imageB
imageC


I think you should a) simplify your question, and b) set up a codepen with example markup and styles. It's not at all clear what you want, or what you have already tried.

Please show us some code (it makes it easier to help you, rather than having to start from scratch). Perhaps show what you consider your closest attempt. Use the <> icon in the editor to create it as a runnable snippet (so provide some images, or pretend images,, which we can load).

@SethWarburton SO asks that code be withing the question, not on an external site which might disappear at any time.

What's the minimum width for A?

Thanks for the advice, I'll try to set up a code block and come back in a bit :)

@AHaworth I don't have a specific number in mind for min-width of A, but roughly no less than 30-40vw.

I can’t see how this problem has a solution in all circumstances. Are there any other constraints?

@AHaworth Mmh, not really. The main constraints are no cropping of the sides of B and C, and fully filling column 2. In the code block, it seems like B and C could increase in size to fill the empty space below them, which would result in column 2 increasing in size too. I haven’t managed to achieve that. B and C won’t have wildly different ratio, just enough to need a flexible solution, not pixel based.

This problem does not have a solution in all circumstances. As a simple example, suppose you even allow A to have width 0 (which you don't want, but we're talking limits here) and suppose B and C are both square images then the maximum height you can get for column 2 is 200vw. What happens if the viewport height is greater than that? So, as currently posed, your question does not have a geometry-based answer, let alone a coding one.

Please edit your post to explain the problem behind your question. For example, why do you want to prevent B and C from cropping, but you are quite happy for A to be cropped?
